# how to initialize useState with apollo graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

How can I use `useState` and set it with value received from graphql before the component renders?

I tried this:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  

  const [me] = useQuery(gql`
    query Me {
      me {
        id
        name
        email
      }
    }
  `);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { data } = await me();

      if (data) {
        setName(data.me.name);
        setEmail(data.me.email);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

And received this error:

```
TypeError: Object is not a function
Profile
src/pages/Profile.js:51
  48 | const [currentPasswordValid, setCurrentPasswordValid] = useState(false);
  49 | const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  50 | 
> 51 | const [me] = useQuery(gql`
     | ^  52 |   query Me {
  53 |     me {
  54 |       id
```

Reason I am trying to do this is to set value of form inputs to the current user values:

```
<TextField value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
```

Comment: FC fn body IS ALL about rendering, it can't be stopped, yielded or sth ... you can only block some parts conditionally - just show/return 'loading' if data not ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using the wrong hook. The `useQuery` will execute automatically after the component is mounted. It will return a `data` a `loading` and an `error` properties that you can use (there are more of them if you look in the documentation, but these are the basic one).

If you want to fire the query manually you can use the `useLazyQuery` hook, that will return the properties above and a callback that you can use to execute the query.

With the `useQuery` you code can look like this:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  

  const { data, loading } = useQuery(gql`
    query Me {
      me {
        id
        name
        email
      }
    }
  `);

  if(loading) {
    return <div>loading...</div>;
  }

  return <TextField value={data.me.name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />;
```

If you prefer to use the lazy query your code can look like this:

```js
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  

  const [me, { data }] = useLazyQuery(gql`
    query Me {
      me {
        id
        name
        email
      }
    }
  `);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await me();
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setName(data.me.name);
      setEmail(data.me.email);
    }
  }, [data])
```

I personally prefer to avoid using lazy queries when I don't have to.

Comment: this did not work for me ```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
(anonymous function)
src/pages/rooms/UpdateRoom.js:77
  74 | `);
  75 | 
  76 | useEffect(async () => {
> 77 |   const { data } = await room({
     | ^  78 |     variables: { id: match.params.id },
  79 |   });
  80 | ```

Comment: I think that the `{ data }` is only available when you create the query not when you run it. I've updated my answer accordingly. But again, the first option (which does not use the lazy query) is much cleaner and safer.

Comment: The first option works but for some reason a I am unable to to type or change the value of the input. The input stays `data.me.name` and can't be changed.

Comment: Yes, the input is immutable. If you want to change it I would advise you to make a mutation to tell your remote server of the change, and then refetch your query, This way the server stays as your single source of truth.

Comment: If you still want to change it locally, you can copy the object: `const newData = { ...data };` (this is a shallow copy, check to see if it works for you). And if you change the `newData` it will not reflect on your server.